# Run Cufon in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, cufon

Is it possible to run the Cufon text replacement script in PHP (or before its sent to the browser)? The reason I ask is that there is a bit of an issue with the displayed HTML being its normal browser rendered text before Cufon is able to draw its magic over it. The user sees a flash of unrendered text (FOUT) before it is replaced with Cufon's awesomeness.  I've noticed that the rendered HTML has some tags generated in place of the HTML (canvas and Cufon tags) text and I thought, what if this could be done in PHP and then sent to the browser so that the browser actually receives the drawn text from the start?. Would this mean porting over the code that draws the text to PHP? This came as a stroke of genius or more likely stupidity last night and was wondering if anyone had some thoughts on the matter. Thanks for reading.

```
 Cufon.replace('div#nav-menu a h5',{
            fontFamily:'United Stencil',
            hover: true,
            hoverables : {h5 : true}
            });         
        Cufon.replace('.stencil',{fontFamily:'United Stencil'})
        Cufon.replace('.heavy',{
            fontFamily : 'United Heavy',
            hover : true,
            hoverables : {
                                h1:true,
                                h2:true,
                                h3:true
                                }
        });
```

Here is the Cufoned HTML:

```
<a class=" heavy" href="/mp_svn/node/5">
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Products" style="width: 65px; height: 16px;">
    <canvas width="77" height="17" style="width: 77px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px;"></canvas>
    <cufontext>Products</cufontext>
</cufon>
```

I would like to send the above HTML to the browser from the beginning, pre-Cufon it is something like:

```
<a href="/mp_svn/node/5">Products</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cufon has a callback function that runs after all text has been replaced: http://groups.google.com/group/cufon/browse_thread/thread/20a8d2edd45f1aa5/1a498d21856405cd

You could either

1. Initially hide the content with CSS, then show it with javascript in the callback, and be absolutely sure you will have no FOUT--but your page will be totally inaccessible for users without JS
2. Or, hide the content with JS when the DOM is ready, and then show it again after the text replacement has occurred. Using jQuery,

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#content').css('visibility', 'hidden');

       Cufon.CSS.ready(function() {
           $('#content').css('visibility, 'visible');
       });
   });
   ```

This should work fine for Firefox/webkit, but there will still be a FOUC in IE before the JS takes effect. You could also use `$('#content').fadeTo(0, 0);` if you want to be able to fade in the content once it's been replaced by Cufon.

**EDIT**
I have figured out a superior way. You go with the #1 approach, hiding content with CSS, but then you throw in a `<noscript>` area with a style declaration that resets `visibility:visible`

That way there will be absolutely no FOUC, and if JS is enabled, they won't have a problem either.

Comment: I'll give your solution a spin. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cufon's built in function

```
Cufon.now();
```

So there's no flash when replacing the text.

Comment: I tried adding Cufon.now() to the end of the JS above and still had the FOUT effect occur. Is there a better place to call it?

Comment: According to the API, ( https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API ) It should be place at the end of the page BUT first in the script tag, could you give it a try ?

Comment: Tried that and still get the FOUT. Thanks for the suggestion though, from the docs it looked like that should have done the trick.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear this doesn't work. It has been working for me all the time. Weird

Answer (score 0):

Great idea, and it's something people have been doing for a while. Here's an early one from 2004: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dynatext/

And a few newer ones

- http://artypapers.com/csshelppile/pcdtr/
- http://www.joaomak.net/util/dtr/

Comment: Thanks John but I think those are a little bit different than the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to use image replacements etc to get the text as I'm trying to keep everything is compliant as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I set my visibility to false in css, call the replace function on Cufon and use the onAfterReplace callback to set the element to visible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    Cufon.replace('h1', { fontFamily: 'alwyn-thin',      
    onAfterReplace:function(el,options){    
         $(el).css('visibility', 'visible');
}});
```